# Do not show some columns in the agColumnsToolPanel

Tags: vuejs2, multiple-columns, hide, ag-grid, show

How could I prevent the `agColumnsToolPanel` from showing specific columns?

E.g. I would like to not show entries for the `foo` and `bar`, but only for the `x`, meaning that it would be impossible to change the `foo`, `bar` columns visibility through the `agColumnsToolPanel`.

[image]

I am using the Ag Grid with Vue.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/tool-panel-columns/#example-custom-layout) shows you have to update the columns in the tool panel.

Relevant code is as follows. Get a reference to the column tool panel and then set the columns to be just your column definitions for foo and bar.

```
    setCustomCols() {
      var columnToolPanel = this.gridApi.getToolPanelInstance('columns');
      columnToolPanel.setColumnLayout([{field: 'foo'}]}, {field: 'bar'});
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to show only `x` and not `foo` and `bar`. you can specify the column list in `columnToolPanel.setColumnLayout` and only those column will show up in the side panel.

here is a simple [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QE9UGISNTaUvcHlX?preview)