# Ag Grid, prevent column hide/show using the column menu

Tags: vue.js, menu, toggle, multiple-columns, ag-grid

How could I prevent column hide/show using the column menu in Ag Grid?

E.g. let us take the example from over [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/tool-panel-columns/).

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Vue example</title>
        <meta charSet="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <style media="only screen">
            html, body, #app {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }

            html {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            body {
                padding: 1rem;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <my-component>Loading Vue example&hellip;</my-component>
        </div>
        <script>
            var appLocation = './';
            var boilerplatePath = '';
            var systemJsMap = {
                "@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-community/core@27.3.0/dist/styles",
                "@ag-grid-community/vue": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-community/vue@27.3.0/",
                "ag-grid-community": "https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@27.3.0/",
                "ag-grid-enterprise": "https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise@27.3.0/",
                "ag-grid-vue": "https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-vue@27.3.0/"
            };
            var systemJsPaths = {
                "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model@27.3.0/dist/client-side-row-model.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-community/core": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-community/core@27.3.0/dist/core.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-community/csv-export": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-community/csv-export@27.3.0/dist/csv-export.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-community/infinite-row-model": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-community/infinite-row-model@27.3.0/dist/infinite-row-model.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/charts": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/charts@27.3.0/dist/charts.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard@27.3.0/dist/clipboard.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel@27.3.0/dist/column-tool-panel.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/core": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/core@27.3.0/dist/core.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/excel-export": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/excel-export@27.3.0/dist/excel-export.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/filter-tool-panel": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/filter-tool-panel@27.3.0/dist/filter-tool-panel.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/master-detail": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/master-detail@27.3.0/dist/master-detail.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/menu": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/menu@27.3.0/dist/menu.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/multi-filter": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/multi-filter@27.3.0/dist/multi-filter.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/range-selection": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/range-selection@27.3.0/dist/range-selection.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/rich-select": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/rich-select@27.3.0/dist/rich-select.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping@27.3.0/dist/row-grouping.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model@27.3.0/dist/server-side-row-model.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/set-filter": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/set-filter@27.3.0/dist/set-filter.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/side-bar": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/side-bar@27.3.0/dist/side-bar.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/sparklines": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/sparklines@27.3.0/dist/sparklines.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/status-bar": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/status-bar@27.3.0/dist/status-bar.cjs.min.js",
                "@ag-grid-enterprise/viewport-row-model": "https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/viewport-row-model@27.3.0/dist/viewport-row-model.cjs.min.js"
            };
        </script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.47/dist/system.js">
        </script>
        <script src="systemjs.config.js">
        </script>
        <script>System.import('./main.js').catch(function(err) { console.error(err); });</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue';
import Vue from 'vue';

const VueExample = {
  template: `
        <div style="height: 100%">
            <div class="example-wrapper">
                <div>
                    <span class="button-group">
                        <button v-on:click="showPivotModeSection()">Show Pivot Mode Section</button>
                        <button v-on:click="showRowGroupsSection()">Show Row Groups Section</button>
                        <button v-on:click="showValuesSection()">Show Values Section</button>
                        <button v-on:click="showPivotSection()">Show Pivot Section</button>
                    </span>
                    
                </div>
                <ag-grid-vue
                
                style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                class="ag-theme-alpine"
                :columnDefs="columnDefs"
                @grid-ready="onGridReady"
                :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
                :sideBar="sideBar"
                :rowData="rowData"></ag-grid-vue>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
  components: {
    'ag-grid-vue': AgGridVue,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      columnDefs: [
        { headerName: 'Name', field: 'athlete', minWidth: 200 },
        { field: 'age', enableRowGroup: true },
        { field: 'country', minWidth: 200 },
        { field: 'year' },
        { field: 'date', suppressColumnsToolPanel: true, minWidth: 180 },
        { field: 'sport', minWidth: 200 },
        { field: 'gold', aggFunc: 'sum' },
        { field: 'silver', aggFunc: 'sum' },
        { field: 'bronze', aggFunc: 'sum' },
        { field: 'total', aggFunc: 'sum' },
      ],
      gridApi: null,
      columnApi: null,
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 100,
        sortable: true,
        enablePivot: true,
      },
      sideBar: null,
      rowData: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.sideBar = {
      toolPanels: [
        {
          id: 'columns',
          labelDefault: 'Columns',
          labelKey: 'columns',
          iconKey: 'columns',
          toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
          toolPanelParams: {
            suppressRowGroups: true,
            suppressValues: true,
            suppressPivots: true,
            suppressPivotMode: true,
            suppressColumnFilter: true,
            suppressColumnSelectAll: true,
            suppressColumnExpandAll: true,
          },
        },
      ],
      defaultToolPanel: 'columns',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showPivotModeSection() {
      var columnToolPanel = this.gridApi.getToolPanelInstance('columns');
      columnToolPanel.setPivotModeSectionVisible(true);
    },
    showRowGroupsSection() {
      var columnToolPanel = this.gridApi.getToolPanelInstance('columns');
      columnToolPanel.setRowGroupsSectionVisible(true);
    },
    showValuesSection() {
      var columnToolPanel = this.gridApi.getToolPanelInstance('columns');
      columnToolPanel.setValuesSectionVisible(true);
    },
    showPivotSection() {
      var columnToolPanel = this.gridApi.getToolPanelInstance('columns');
      columnToolPanel.setPivotSectionVisible(true);
    },
    onGridReady(params) {
      this.gridApi = params.api;
      this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

      const updateData = (data) => params.api.setRowData(data);

      fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => updateData(data));
    },
  },
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'my-component': VueExample,
  },
});
```

style.css:

```
.example-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#myGrid {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.button-group {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

When I go to the Name's column menu I can hide/show the Age column. I do not want to be able to be able to do that. How could I prevent this functionality?

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: see if my previous answer to similar question helps you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72435827/do-not-show-some-columns-in-the-agcolumnstoolpanel/72441727#72441727

Comment: @sandeepjoshi, in ur example all three columns can be toggled from the column toggle menu. The menu I am talking is shown if u click the burger button in the column header. Also, in this question there is no columns tool panel whatsoever, so ur previous question bears no value here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using AG Grid standalone or with Adaptable?
If you are using Adaptable also as we are then they have functions you can provide which will set whether or not the Column menu should appear in a given column.
See: https://docs.adaptabletools.com/guide/reference-options-menu#showadaptablecolumnmenu

And for Column Menus generally see:  https://docs.adaptabletools.com/guide/ui-column-menu